# SQLite: actualizar campo mediante un trigger

Tags: sqlite, trigger, update

Tengo 2 campos datetime: startDateTime y endDateTime ...
Quiero que cuando ingreso una startDateTime mayor que endDateTime, la endDateTime tome el valor de startDateTime.

### **He intentado sin resultados**:

```
CREATE TRIGGER validate_start_or_end_dateTime_before_update_user<br>
    BEFORE UPDATE ON users<br>
    WHEN OLD.startDateTime<>NEW.startDateTime OR OLD.endDateTime<>NEW.endDateTime<br>
BEGIN<br>
SELECT<br>
    CASE<br>
        WHEN NEW.startDateTime<>OLD.startDateTime AND NEW.startDateTime>OLD.endDateTime THEN<br>
        OLD.endDateTime=NEW.startDateTime<br>
        WHEN NEW.endDateTime<>OLD.endDateTime AND NEW.startDateTime>OLD.endDateTime THEN<br>
        OLD.startDateTime=NEW.endDateTime<br>
    END;<br>
END;<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Correcto, esto funcionó:

```
CREATE TRIGGER validate_startDateTime_before_update_users
   BEFORE UPDATE ON users
   WHEN OLD.endDateTime<NEW.startDateTime
BEGIN
    UPDATE users SET endDateTime=NEW.startDateTime WHERE _id=OLD._id;
END;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS validate_endDateTime_before_update_users;
CREATE TRIGGER validate_endDateTime_before_update_users
   BEFORE UPDATE ON users
   WHEN NEW.endDateTime<OLD.startDateTime
BEGIN
    UPDATE users SET startDateTime=NEW.endDateTime WHERE _id=OLD._id;
END;
```